# Need css background image to fit with the screen

Tags: css, background

I just coding a blogger template, I just want to remove the black area from the background, and add a picture to the red area.

Template : http://loremipsumdt.blogspot.com/

[image]

Comment: I saw there is no black area on the template. To put a picture to the red area, please provide first the code layout.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. for the black area i just want to resize the top off the background.

Comment: wich part of the code layout?

Comment: Yes, I saw on http://loremipsumdt.blogspot.com/, there is no the black area. Or could you please provide the code ?

Comment: the code you write to create the website.

Comment: check here : http://pastebin.com/KPzKgC2T

Comment: http://loremipsumdt.blogspot.co.id doesn't has the black area so I can't inspect.

Comment: i just want to remove this part from the top or resize it http://i.imgur.com/lgxYyPw.png

Comment: anny suggestions?